# creating one function that can convert list of different classes

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

i have 3 classes,
class Z, 
    calss A implements OInterface and calss B implements OInterface
    .

I want to create a function  that converts a list of Z to a list of OInterface

```
List<OInterface > myfunction(List<Z> mylist){
     List <OInterface > ret=new  List <OInterface >;
     for (Z z : mylist){
          OInterface tmp=new OInterface ()
          tmp.a=z.a
          tmp.b=z.b
          ret.add (tmp)
      }
     return ret;
}
```

that i can use like so :

```
List<Z> zzz=...
List<A> aaa=myfunction(zzz);
List<B> aaa=myfunction(zzz);
```

of course this does not compile, its more like pseudo code to show what i want to do.

is there a way of implementing this?

Comment: The complexity is in how you convert a `Z` to a `A`.  It would be much simpler to write a conversion method for `list of Z to A` and `list of Z to B` rather than write a generic method which does both.

Comment: If `OInterface` is an interface it would not support fields and thus `tmp.a = ...` is not possible.

Comment: In your example you say that Class B implements OInterface and Class Z, but in the pseudo code you want myFunction to convert a Z into a OInterface. A Z will not always be castable to a OInterface unless Z also implements OInterface. Do you mean List<OInterface> myfunction(List<B> mylist)?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  You show that you want to use the same method `myfunction(List<Z> my list)` to return either a `List<A>` or `List<B>`, and that is simply impossible in Java: you can't overload based on return type.  The signature you have provided, `List<OInterface> myfunction(List<Z> mylist)` will always take a `List` of `Z` objects (which, as you say, do not implement `OInterface`), and return a list of *some other* objects which do implement `OInterface` (either `A`, or `B`, some other class that implements `OInterface`, or a mix of all three).  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

As Z does not implement `OInterface`, you will never be able to '*convert*' Z to an `OInterface`, by any method. This is obviously by design - the very reason you have `OInterface` in the first place is to **ensure** you can always guarantee the *shape* of the inheriting objects.

You either will have to make Z implement `OInterface`, or write a method which converts a Z to an A and/or Z to B, then create a list of A or B.

Only then, can you consider it a list of OInterface elements - you can then do something like:

```
OInterface anObject = aaa[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusing names, call the static method  process:

```
new Processor<Z,A> () {
  public A process(Z z){
    A a = new A();
    a.addSomethingFrom(z);
   return a ;
}
}
```

as parameter

```
public interface Processor<A,R> {
    R process(A a);
}

public static <Input, Output> List<Output> process(List<Input> as, Processor<Input, Output> processor) {
    List<Output> ret = new ArrayList<Output>();
    for (Input a: as) {
        ret.add(processor.process(a));
    }
    return ret;
}
```